# Css a.current doesnt work for one id but works for another

Tags: html, css

I'm in an early stage with developing a website. 
I encountered this problem: a.current works perfectly for one id but doesnt for another.

Here is the exact code

```
    #top-menu
{
    width:965;
    height:27;
}

#top-menu ul
{
    float:left;
    margin: 5 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#top-menu li
{   
    margin-left:5;
    display: inline;
}


#top-menu a
{
    padding: 7px 7px 4px 7px;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:-9;
    color:#000;
    font-size:12;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:100;
}

#top-menu a:hover
{
    border-bottom-color:#FFF;
    background-color:#FFF;  
}


#top-menu a.current
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

/**/

```
    #glavnimeni
{
padding-right:0;
width:965;
height:28;
margin-top:-3;
}


#glavnimeni ul
{
    height:28;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    background-image:url(../images/navigacija.png);
    width:965;

}

#glavnimeni ul li
{   
    display: inline;
    height:28;
}

#glavnimeni ul li a
{
    padding:9 10 7 10;
    color:#fff;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

#glavnimeni ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    border-bottom-color:#FFF;
}

#glavnimeni a.current
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

It works perfectly for #top-menu, but it doesn't work for #glavnimeni .
Here is the code of both divs where I use those ids:

```
    <div id="top-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="default.asp">Prijavi se</a></li>
            <li><a href="default2.asp">Registruj se</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Prati nas</a></li>
                        <li<a href="#">Pretraga</a></li>

</div>
```

/**/

```
    <div id="glavnimeni">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="default.asp">Početna</a></li>
            <li><a href="default2.asp">Vijesti</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Škola</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sekcije & Takmičenja</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Galerija</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">O nama</a></li>
        </ul>


  </div>
```

I just can't think of anything what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's because none of your `<a>` tags have a `class="current"` attribute.

I also notice a coding mistake: Change `<li<a href="#">Pretraga</a></li>` to:

```
<li><a href="#">Pretraga</a></li>
</ul>
```

In #top-menu.

Comment: Thanks now it works for #glavnimeni too.

But how is it possible that it works for #top-menu without class="current" in the <a> tag?